# Existe alguma forma de criar um link secundário (uma espécie de bit.ly) para um outro link e fazer com que ele expire depois de, por exemplo, 1 horas?

Tags: url, link

Tenho um link específico que dá desconto para uma compra, mas não posso passar esse link para os clientes porque ele é fixo e a pessoa teria acesso indiscriminado ao desconto. 
Por isso, pensei que uma solução, poderia ser criar um link secundário que redirecionasse para esse principal, mas que o secundário expirasse depois de, por exemplo, 1 hora que foi enviado.
É possível fazer isso?

Comment: A partir do momento que a pessoa fosse redirecionada para esse link, ela não conseguiria pegar fácil esse link na barra de endereços e entrar indiscriminadamente toda vez que quisesse um descontinho no seu site?

Comment: Poderia enviar um código junto com o link.

Fazer o cadastro do código e verificar a validade do mesmo no momento do acesso.

Comment: Veja se isso te ajuda: http://www.flexurl.com/, Mas, porém, entretanto, o melhor seria você criar uma url que tenha um ID de promoção identificável pelo seu sistema e não usar encurtadores.